# perl regex match any number that is not

Tags: php, regex, perl

given a string:

```
//foo.bar/baz/123/index.html
```

I am trying to match the number after baz, so long as it is not 123.

```
//foo.bar/baz/124/index.html (WOULD MATCH)
//foo.bar/baz/123/index.html (WOULD NOT MATCH)
```

How can I express this?  I keep trying things like:

```
/baz\/d+^(123)/index/
```

but have not been successful.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use negative look-ahead to assert that there is not `123` after `baz/`. Then go on to match with `\d+`:

```
m~baz/(?!123\b)\d+/index~
```

In Perl, you can use different delimiter when your regex pattern already contains `/`, to avoid escaping them. Here I've used `~`.

---

If the substring to not allow is fixed to be `baz/123`, you can also do it with `index()` function:

```
$str = "//foo.bar/baz/124/index.html";
$needle = "/baz/123/";

if (index($str, $needle) == -1) {
    print "Match found\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit, that's great.  This is currently matching correctly except that it does not match on //foo.bar/baz/1234/index.html, is there a condition I can add that says "only do not match 123" so that 1234 would match?

Comment: @dcoffey3296 Edited regex. Just need to add word boundary after `123`.

Comment: `index('//foo.bar/baz/123/index.html', '/baz/123/') == -1` do the same?